# Imagen no se visualiza al ser llamada por API en el navegador usando node.js

Tags: nodejs, angularjs, imagen, cookies, navegador-web

Tengo una API en node.js, la cual me devuelve una imagen al enviarle un id de un producto(las imágenes se almacenan con anterioridad con nombre del id del ítem correspondiente), según la consola se retorna correctamente pero el navegador no es capaz de visualizarla, sé que la api funciona porque la utilizo con un frontend en angula.js, al ser llamada esta api con el frontend se visualiza la imagen correctamente en la vista, pero al pasar la url de la api directamente a un navegador (donde no se haya cargado el frontend con anterioridad) no se ve la imagen, sólo funciona si primero se carga la imagen con la vista de Detalle del Item y luego poniendo la url (http://localhost:8000/api/image/image/21500) de la api en el navegador, es como si fuera un problema de cookies del navegador.

Lo que esta comentado era mi primera forma de enviar la imagen al frontend, lo cual funcionaba para la vista.

```
async function getImage(req, res) {
  const imageName = req.params.imageName;
  const imagePath = await getImagePath(imageName);
  if (imagePath) {
    // console.log('existe img:',imagePath);
    // res.sendFile(imagePath);
    // res.status(200);
    const image = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    res.type('image/png'); // o el tipo correcto (jpg, png, etc)
    res.send(image);

    console.log('Image returned successfully');
    res.status(200);
  } else {
    console.log('La imagen no existe');
    res.json({
      data: [],
      status: 0,
    });
    res.status(400);
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: puede ser algún middleware, o que falte un header,  `curl -I "http://localhost:8000/api/image/image/21500"` que te dice? `curl -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" "http://localhost:8000/api/image/image/21500"` funciona?

Comment: algunos puntos importantes:
Status 200 OK indica que la petición fue procesada correctamente.

Content-Type image/png confirma que se está devolviendo una imagen PNG.

Content-Length coincide con el tamaño de la imagen.

No veo el cuerpo de la respuesta (la imagen) porque curl imprime una advertencia, pero creo que es normal.

como decía la api funciona correctamente, sólo que al poner la url en el navegador sin antes haber cargador la imagen con el frontend no se visualiza pero según el navegador la petición fue exitosa, lo otro que debería revisar sería el middleware tal vez.

Comment: `curl -I ` es haders only, es para verificar content type y content length. con -H podes ir probando headers, un middleware puede estar interceptando el options como parte del mecanismo cors ( `curl -H "Origin: http://localhost:8000" --verbose "http://localhost:8000/api/image/image/21500"` puede dar pistas ), o requiriendo un header para continuar ( el  requestedwith de ajax o una cookie ).  imagenes por lo general viven en el cache del navegador, salvo q tenga un tag o expiry. btw es correcto el url `/image/image/:id` o habra algun asunto ahi q lo acomoda si el request viene desde angularjs ?